# Django / Celery: autodiscover_tasks error: NoneType object not iterable.

Tags: python, django, celery

I am setting up Django-celery (Django 1.5.5, most recent versions of celery & Django-celery). 
I have created tasks in an app, and a celery.py in proj/proj, following http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(settings.INSTALLED_APPS, related_name='tasks')`

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

When I run manage.py runserer, I get TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable. 
Using $ celery -A project -l info starts the celery worker, but it only finds the debug task shown above, not the task in the app which I want to run. 
I would be grateful for any suggestions on how to resolve this

Comment: It would be nice if you could post the actual full traceback of the error.

Comment: i made autodiscover_tasks return [] instead of None when in _RACE_CONDITION (line 269) not sure if this is the right approach..

Comment: You should not evaluate `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` at module level.  This was fixed in the Celery docs some time ago where the new tutorial example uses: `app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)`. See: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html (note that you may also have to upgrade celery to the latest version)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue. I think the problem is that [docs/instructions/versions](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) are off/out of date.

> Previous versions of Celery required a separate library to work with Django, but since 3.1 this is no longer the case

Although later on it prompts you to install django-celery. If you simply install django-celery, by default (not sure why), it will install 3.0.23, and downgrade your celery to version 3.0.24. You can check what versions you have with `$pip freeze`

`$pip install celery==3.1`

`$pip install django-celery==3.1`

Should help

[1](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html